# Index based List view using android

Tags: android, listview

I am currently working on an Android application which shows various lists. I would like to create a list view like this: [image] .. How can I achieve this? I tried AlphabetIndexer for fastscrolling ListView, and   IndexableListView. But I couldn't do it like this. Kindly help me in this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use an ExpandableListView.

Comment: now Is it oK Mr. Christopher Perry ?

Comment: No, there's a horrible iOS looking back button on the top left. ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). It does exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried that ExpandableListView and it works awesome. can you provide me simple example for how can I use Filter for shows alphabetical and letters numeric on ListView Index ?